# Call a function specified in variable in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a input hidden type which specifies the function that needs to be called. How can I do it using Javascript/Jquery

```
<input type="hidden" name="extrafunction" id="extrafunction" value="edit_data_provider/DataProviderChange1" />
```

and in Javascript file

```
        var fullfunctionName = $('#extrafunction').val();
        var control_name    = fullfunctionName.split('/')[0];
        var function_name   = fullfunctionName.split('/')[1];
        if(control_name == client_control_name)
        {
            //The function call which is in function_name var should come here

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use :

```
window[functionName](arguments);
```

Hope this helps.

---

```js
var functionName="my_function";
function my_function(){
   console.log('test from my_function');
}
window[functionName]();
```